# Android - How do I manage multiple instances of a single fragment with different content?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to be able to setText and getText of Views of individual Fragments. As it is now, when I setText of a Framgent's TextView it changes the text of that View in all Fragments.

I've been experimenting by moving things around, but here is my code as of this moment:

Fragment class

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment{

    View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_fragment, container, false);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.huh);
        //tv.setText("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");

        return view;
    }

    public void setText(String asdf) {
        TextView test = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.huh);
        test.setText(asdf);
    }


}
```

Activity Class

```
    public class Manage extends BaseActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.manage);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();
        //fragment.setText("ASDF");
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.test_fragment, fragment, "testtag");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

The framgent.xml is pretty plain; just a single TextView.

Comment: You can definitely use multiple instances of the same fragment class independently. You need to show us your code though so that we can help you with your particular problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fragments are added to stack with a parameter named tag. In your case you've added your fragment with "testtag".

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.test_fragment, fragment, "testtag");
```

If you create multiple instances of same fragment and add them with unique tags, then you are able to get them with that unique tags. When you get a fragment then you can reach its content.

```
FragmentManager fm = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment testtagFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("testtag"); 
View targetView = testtagFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.anyViewInsideContentOfYourFragment);
```

Edit:

> I want to be able to setText and getText of Views of individual
>   Fragments.

This question has 2 parts.

1. To setText while initializing you have to pass your initial
   parameters to your fragment while creating its instance. I suggest
   you to use a static `newInstance` method for this. [See sample
   here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)
2. To getText read my answer above. Note that, you can get the content of a fragment after its `onCreateView` method is executed. So If you try to call getView method of a fragment at your activities onCreate method (after you add the fragment), that will return null. You can get its content successfully under a click event to test that, and use get or set operations of any view on that fragment's content.

Comment: Thanks, it looks good, but I'm having another problem now. My target is Android 2.3, so I'm using [android.support.v4.app](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/package-summary.html). I've imported android.support.v4.app.* but that version of FragmentTransaction doesn't have a findFragmentById().

Comment: Sorry my mistake. You can get fragments from fragmentManager. I've edited my answer.

Comment: 'View targetView = testtagFragment.getView()' 
is giving me a runtime error (984)

Comment: Share your logcat please. getView is the right method to get the content view of a fragment. See docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getView(). Share your logcat output.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/gJNvBf2T it only happens at getView() I wrapped both that and findFragmentByTag in a try block, but it still says uncaught exception

Comment: I updated my answer. You may read more about fragment's life cycle. I hope I'm clear on my answer and that helps you.