# Differentiate two instances of the same Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have this layout file for the activity that contains the fragments:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/RelLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="sguancicosimo.com.planmytrip.NewTrip1"
android:orientation="vertical">




<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Where"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/Where"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_location_city_black_24dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonDone"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Where"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done_black_24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/departureDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/departureDate"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Where"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="showCalFrag"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/returnDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/returnDate"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/departureDate"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="showCalFrag"/> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

The fragments are created at runtime when clicking on the two TextViews (showCalFrag method).The fragment consists in a CalendarView, I want to keep the dates selected by the user, sending them at the Activity, but I don't know how to differentiate the two CalendarView as they are two instances of the same Fragment and also I have problems letting the user change the dates that were already selected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - How do I manage multiple instances of a single fragment with different content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19757488/android-how-do-i-manage-multiple-instances-of-a-single-fragment-with-different)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create an `enum` like:

```
public enum FragmentType{

FROM_DATE,TO_DATE

}
```

and in the fragment create a new variable with this enum type:

```
private FragmentType fragmentType;

public void setFragmentType(FragmentType type){ this.fragmentType = type;}
```

and when calling the fragment:

```
YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
fragment.setFragmentType(FragmentType.FROM_DATE); // for the first textView 
fragment.setFragmentType(FragmentType.TO_DATE); // for the second textView
```

and then you can differentiate between the two instances

Comment: How can I retrieve the FragmentType from the activity class?

Comment: create a getter method for the FragmentType,like: 
`public FragmentType getFragmentType(){ return fragmentType;}` 
and from the instance of the fragment you can call it to get the type